# Yahoo gecoding API in R

Tags: r, api, yahoo, httr

I am trying to do a batch geocode with the Yahoo BOSS api from R.

It is currently throwing an error based on credentials - any idea how I can get this to succeed?

```
  myapp <- oauth_app("yahoo",
        key =     "my key",
        secret =  "my secret"  
               )     
 yahoo <- oauth_endpoint("get_request_token", "request_auth", "get_token",
                    base_url =     "https://yboss.yahooapis.com/geo/placefinder")

token <- oauth1.0_token(myapp, yahoo)

sig <- sign_oauth1.0(myapp, token$oauth_token, token$oauth_token_secret)

GET("https://yboss.yahooapis.com/geo/placefinder", 
sig)
```

Comment: Describe exactly what the error message says. Since we don't have your credentials, we can't try your code ourselves to see what the problem is.

Comment: You can use Jeff Allen's package `rydn` at https://github.com/trestletech/rydn - implements a wrapper for this API already

Comment: Have you set up payment info? https://info.yahoo.com/legal/us/yahoo/boss/pricing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Yahoo uses a weird authentication strategy that isn't compatible with a simple `oauth_endpoint` function. You can see the general flow I use in the [rydn package](https://github.com/trestletech/rydn) that @Scott pointed out [here](https://github.com/trestletech/rydn/blob/master/R/place-finder.R#L160-L174).

You might benefit from just using that package, or feel free to leverage the working example I have there in your own stuff.

Comment: Top notch, @Jeff! Been fishing around for this for a while now.